# xdg-email can't find thunderbird

Tags: chromium, thunderbird, email, xdg, xdg-open

Clicking a mailto link in chromium-browser it executes

```
xdg-email mailto:example@example.com
```

(or maybe without "mailto:", which seems to be the same thing). In my case this opens kmail instead of thunderbird, and if I purge kmail it just opens nothing (throwing "Could not find 'kmail' executable." in terminal). Of course I made thunderbird my standard mail application, and

```
xdg-open mailto:example@example.com
```

does open thunderbird correctly. How can I fix xdg-email (or worse, make chromium use xdg-open instead)?

PS: I found [this hack](http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/3063-solved-chromium-mailto-link-doesnt-open-on-thunderbird-xdg-email/?p=28319), but there should be a clean way, don't you think?

Answer (score -3):

You could try reinstall both, and then again set the default, and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird

sudo apt-get install kmail
```

and then enter this

```
sudo dkms-reconfigure chromium
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: There is no command `dkms-reconfigure`, do you mean `dkms reconfigure chromium-browser` or maybe `dpkg-reconfigure chromium-browser`?

Comment: Install dkms whit this command sudo apt-get install dkms

Comment: I purged both programs, reinstalled them and did `dkms reconfigure chromium` as well as `dkms reconfigure chromium-browser`, but it just throws `I do not know how to handle chromium.`(or `…-browser.` of course) and doesn't work.